# How to sort 20 RSS links by pubdate and display all in one

Tags: android, sorting, rss

I'm developing an Android app which gets data from at least 20 RSS links. But, I need to display all the data of these links sorted by `pubdate`.

I fetch the data and store it in database. Then, I get the data from database sorted by time. But, this is ineffective and time-consuming way because it saves data in database and then, retrieves it to display.

There is another way which stores each RSS link in `ArrayList` and merge 20 `ArrayList`'s  in one. And, sort it. But, it is time-consuming too.

How can I sort data efficiently?

Comment: little bit unclear . anyway can you provide your main RSS link which you want to parse in which you are getting pubdate?

Comment: can you show some code or be more specific, question is little bit unclear

Answer (score 1):

This may help you.

```
   Collections.sort(myFeedsList, new Comparator<RssItemModel>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(RssItemModel lhs, RssItemModel rhs) {
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz");
            try {
                Date date1 = formatter.parse(rhs.getPubDate());
                Date date2 = formatter.parse(lhs.getPubDate());
                return date1.compareTo(date2);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return 0;
        }
    });
```